# Match center of a Tile Layer with center of the Map on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jsp, maps, leaflet, coordinates

I am trying to make a Map of a Distribution Center using a flat image of the place. I need to be able to zoom in and out keeping a good quality of the image. So far I've been using Leaflet to draw the Map and MapTiler to create a tile schema that makes possible zooming without any quality loss and good performance.

I have everything set and working, but I need my Tile Layer center to match with the Map center. No matter what I do the Tile Layer top-left corner always starts at the (0,0) coordinate of the Map.

At zoom level 3, for example, my image is 1536x1280px, so the top-left corner should be at coordinate (-768,640) of the Map when talking about absolute pixel coordinates.

Here is my main script:

```
var map = L.map('map',{
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,  
    center:[0,0]
}).setView([0,0],3);

//mapHeight and mapWidth are the pixel dimensions of the flat image at max zoom level.
//In this case it's 6144x4608px. By default the tiles size is 256x256px.

var southWest = map.unproject([ 0, mapHeight], getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([ mapWidth, 0 ], getMaxZoom());
var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

L.tileLayer('tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    noWrap:true,        
    bounds:mapBounds
}).addTo(map);
```

I have messed with the center, setView and bounds, but no success in making the Tile Layer move.

The documentation of Leaflet can be found here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Leaflet, tile coordinates are tightly bound to an internal mechanism - pixel coordinates.

For every zoom level, coordinates in `LatLng` get projected to the CRS coordinates (that's EPSG:4326→EPSG:3857 for earth maps and a vertical flip for `L.CRS.Simple` maps), then the CRS coordinate gets scaled by a factor dependant on the zoom level to give a pixel coordinate. Layers (tiles, markers, etc) are drawn using these pixel coordinates.

For "normal" tiles (of both `GridLayer` and `TileLayer`), the `{x}` and `{y}` fields on the tile template URL are simply the pixel coordinate divided by the tile size. A 256px tile at pixel `[0, 0]` will have the tile coords `[0, 0]`, a tile at pixel `[512, 256]` will have `[2, 1]` and so on.

If you read the code for `L.TileLayer.WMS`, however, you'll notice that the tile URLs don't necessarily depend on the tile coordinates.

Back to your problem. You can overcome it by using the same strategy of `L.TileLayer.WMS`: overriding the `getTileUrl` method, with something like:

```
var t = L.tileLayer(…);

t.getTileUrl = function(coords) {
   var myZ = coords.z;
   var myX = coords.x + (8 * Math.pow(2, myZ - 3)); 
   var myY = coords.y + (6 * Math.pow(2, myZ - 3)); 

   return '/tile/' + myZ + '/' + myX + '/' + myY + '.png';
}
```

The code is simplistic (and I haven't bothered to make the math so that things fit where they should), but that should put you on the right track.

---

A different way to achieve the same would be to create a custom `L.CRS` based on `L.CRS.Simple` which applies a *translation* transformation to convert between `LatLng`s and CRS coordinates. If the code in `src/geo/crs/CRS.Simple.js` and `src/geometry/Transformation.js` in the Leaflet repo makes sense to you, I suggest you try this approach.

Comment: Thank you! The first solution has solved my issue. I just had to change little things,but the idea of overriding the method was the core of the solution. Should I post the final code and considerations? If yes, where should I? Can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation, but I wish you all the best.

Comment: If you wish, you can append it as an addendum to your original question, there are some people who do that. Make sure to not modify the original question, as to provide context for future readers.